How to make data from a python DLL available to Labview
I have this Python DLL from Mantracourt Engineering for reading from a loadcell via wireless telemetry. The hardware consists of a unit connected to PC by USB and similar unit attached to the loadcell. I have just about got it to work in Visual Studio and the output looks like that below. I want to access the item called Value from Labview and looking on labview forum it says I just need to add the following code in Python. I am very new to Python and coding proper but have done quite a lot of graphical coding. So my question is how to make that data item accessible?
I have looked at the code and identified two locations that refer to the output (bottom) presumably I could add the piece of code somewhere and make MyFunction = Value?
Any comments gratefully received.
Mantracourt driver location
def MyFunction_Add(num1, num2):
    return num1+num2

**Visual Studio.
Pairing...
Successfuly paired with device ID: fd882e with Data Tag: 882e
Model: T24-SA
Press any key to command device to resume normal operation
Stay Awake Mode now on.
Registered callbacks
Data Provider Callback: Base Station: 1   Data Tag: 882e   Value: -0.5397806167602539
Status: 16   Error: No   Low Batt: No   RSSI: -25   CV: 150
Registered callbacks
Data Provider Callback: Base Station: 1   Data Tag: 882e   Value: -0.5413785576820374
Status: 16   Error: No   Low Batt: No   RSSI: -27   CV: 148**
import ctypes

def callbackdp( BaseStation,  DataTag,  Value,  Status,  Err,  LowBatt,  RSSI,  CpV ):
    print("Data Provider Callback: Base Station: {}   Data Tag: {}   Value: {}   Status: {}   Error: {}   Low Batt: {}   RSSI: {}   CV: {}".format(BaseStation, hex(DataTag).lstrip("0x"), Value, Status,  "Yes" if Err == 1 else "No" , "Yes" if LowBatt == 1 else "No", RSSI*-1, CV))
    return


                if iDATAPROVIDERINFO(DataTag, byref(BaseStation), byref(Value), byref(Status), byref(RSSI), byref(CV), byref(Err), byref(LowBatt), byref(msInterval), byref(msLastReceived)) == 1:                  
                    print("Data Provider Info for Data Tag: {} Base Station: {}   Value: {}   Status: {}   RSSI: {}   CV: {}   Error: {}   Low Batt: {}   ".format(hex(DataTag).lstrip("0x"), BaseStation.value, Value.value, Status.value, RSSI.value*-1, CV.value, "Yes" if Err.value == 1 else "No" , "Yes" if LowBatt.value == 1 else "No"))                                        
                else:
                    print("No data received from Data Tag: {}\n".format(userin))
            else:
                print("Invalid Data Tag entered!\n")


